# mongoose couldn't connect to mongodb in docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

mongoose couldn't authenticate with docker mongodb container.
**Note**: mongo is in docker and my API app out of the docker.

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${MONGO_USERNAME}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
      MONGO_INITDB_DB: "${MONGO_DB}"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

.env:

```
MONGO_USERNAME=root
MONGO_PASSWORD=123456
MONGO_DB=nodeApp
```

db.js (database connection file):

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const uri = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${process.env.MONGO_DB}`;
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      user: process.env.MONGO_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
    });
    console.log("Database connection completed successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

and finally this is what I got from console:
[image]

I can connect to mongo with mongoose with username and password.

Comment: Edit `/etc/mongod.conf`'s `bindip` to add the IP address connecting to `mongo` from.

Answer (score 2):

Docker only supports using default environment variables to be used like what you did in your code.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Docker added support to env filed since version 1.3 (as I remember). The soloution is to use  `env_file` key in your yml file.

```
  services:
    db:
        image: mongo:latest
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${MONGO_USERNAME}"
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
            MONGO_INITDB_DB: "${MONGO_DB}"
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - mongo_data:/data/db
        env_file:
            - mongo_variables.env
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost use your ip on database configuration.

Replace this `DBurl=mongodb://localhost:27017/`

to this one `DBurl=mongodb://X.X.X.X:27017/` ( X.X.X.X means your ip address )on your database configuration file.

On your docker-compose.yml file

- Inside of services of api add CONNECTIONSTRING.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
 api:
    build: node-server                                ## as i am using node       
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb://X.X.X.X:27017/     ##X.X.X.X means your ip address
    
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "${MONGO_USERNAME}"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MONGO_PASSWORD}"
      MONGO_INITDB_DB: "${MONGO_DB}"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

Comment: how can i get my ipaddress? docker ps? you mean?

Comment: @ShaSha I Don't know if you got a response or not but if your using docker compose you should use the service name instead of looking for the IP. You would want your mongodb url to look like this.
`mongodb://db:27017/`

Answer (score 0):

you see that in the inspector docker -> port of your container -> (0.0.0.0:27017)

`mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/`

;)